# Installing tensorflow extended python 3 on windows

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I tried to pip install tfx==0.13.0 on windows 10 machine and I get this error has anyone been able to pip install tfx==0.13.0

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ml-metadata<0.14,>=0.13.2 (from tfx==0.13.0) (from versions: 0.12.0.dev0, 0.13.0.dev0, 0.13.1.dev0) No matching distribution found for ml-metadata<0.14,>=0.13.2 (from tfx==0.13.0)`

Comment: What is the exact version of Python you are using

Comment: What exactly is the version of Python you are using. Because, as per the official documentation provided in the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide, TFX is tested to work on Python 3.5.

Comment: Python 3.6, thanks Tensorflow Support for pointing this out. I will try it on python 3.5

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but TFX doesn't support windows as of now and hence the issue. Please try switiching to Linux based systems. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TensorflowSupport is it still the case that TFX does not support Windows?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tensorflow Support in comments `TFX` does not support windows as of now.

Curently it supports both `Linux` and `MacOS` only.

Latest stable `tfx` version is `0.25.0` and tested python versions are `3.6` and `3.7`.